# Regex for two possible character counts

Tags: java, android, regex

I need a regular expression for allowing two diferent character counts.
I only want to allow a string whose length is either 5 or 7 characters but not any of the values in between.

For example: for 5 and 7

```
asdfg = ok
asdfgh = fail
asdfghj = ok
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.{5}(?:.{2})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG8kO3/1)